# Where can I find the source code for mounting my digital camera?

Tags: mount, camera, source-code

I have some simple digital camera for my kids with only internal memory. I do have some windows software for it to import the photos. The windows software looks a bit outdated, but it works.

When I connected it on an Ubuntu machine to read the USB ID (`ID 0979:0227 Jeilin Technology Corp., Ltd JL2005B/C/D Toy Camera`) it worked instantly. The memory was mounted as a drive, I could see the photos and copy them!

But when I go on holiday I will have neither a Windows PC nor an Ubuntu machine nearby. I will only have my Android tablet, which supports USB On-the-go.

When I connect the camera via the USB OTG connector, the camera gives a bleep and on my tablet I see a message "USB connector attached". But I don't see a mounted drive (which I do see when I connect a simple USB memory stick to my tablet).

If there isn't any app to mount and read the photos, then maybe I have to write my own. Does somebody know where I can find the Ubuntu sources for mounting my digital camera, so I could use this to create an android app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it's based on [gPhoto](http://www.gphoto.org/).